# zmq_getsockopt returns EINVAL on windows x64 when local address of ZMQ_FD option_val passed

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, zeromq, mingw-w64

On windows x64 passing the address of a local variable to zmq_getsockopt for ZMQ_FD consistently results in EINVAL. The code below is the smallest possible to reproduce the problem.

```
#include <zmq.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                 

void zmq_perror(const char*);                                                                                                                                                                                      

int main(void)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    const char *endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:7100";                                                                                                                                                                 

    void *ctx    = zmq_ctx_new();                                                                                                                                                                                  
    if (ctx == NULL) { zmq_perror("zmq_ctx_new"); }                                                                                                                                                                

    void *socket = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_DEALER);                                                                                                                                                                    
    if (socket == NULL) { zmq_perror("zmq_socket"); }                                                                                                                                                              

    int rc;                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    rc = zmq_connect(socket, endpoint);                                                                                                                                                                            
    if ( rc == -1 ) { zmq_perror("zmq_connect"); }                                                                                                                                                                 


    /*** This results in EINVAL ***/                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    int fd;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    size_t fd_size = sizeof (fd);                                                                                                                                                                                
    rc = zmq_getsockopt(socket, ZMQ_FD, &fd, &fd_size);                                                                                                                                                          
    if (rc == -1) { zmq_perror("zmq_getsockopt"); }                                                                                                                                                              


    /*** This works without issue ***/
    /*                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    int *fd        = malloc(sizeof(int));                                                                                                                                                                          
    size_t fd_size = sizeof (fd);                                                                                                                                                                                  
    rc = zmq_getsockopt(socket, ZMQ_FD, fd, &fd_size);                                                                                                                                                             
    if (rc == -1) { zmq_perror("zmq_getsockopt"); }  
    */                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

void zmq_perror(const char *f)                                                                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", f, zmq_strerror(zmq_errno()));                                                                                                                                                     
    abort();                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Running the above using the first (manpage) form always produces:

```
zmq_getsockopt: Invalid argument
```

However the second, commented out form using malloc has no issues.  This makes zero sense to me since passing the address of the local variable to zmq_getsockopt is perfectly legal.

This problem only manifests with 64 bit binaries on windows; 32 bit binaries on windows or 64 bit binaries on linux have no issue.

It also seems to only be an issue with the ZMQ_FD socket option.  ZMQ_TYPE and ZMQ_SNDHWM worked without issue.

Is there some weird behavior related to ZMQ_FD on windows x64 that I'm not aware of?

**Update**

So I just noticed that my "working" code is actually erroneous.

```
sizeof(fd)
```

is taking the sizeof a *pointer* in the second form.  In fact, it has nothing to do with malloc, as once I change it to sizeof(int) as it should be I get EINVAL again:

```
/* Fail */
int *fd        = malloc(sizeof(int));                                                                                                                                                                          
size_t fd_size = sizeof(int);                                                                                                                                                                                  
rc = zmq_getsockopt(socket, ZMQ_FD, fd, &fd_size);                                                                                                                                                             
if (rc == -1) { zmq_perror("zmq_getsockopt"); }
```

It turns out I apparently need to use a 64bit integer type with ZMQ_FD on windows x64

```
/* Success! */
uint64_t fd;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
size_t fd_size = sizeof(uint64_t);                                                                                                                                                                             
rc = zmq_getsockopt(socket, ZMQ_FD, &fd, &fd_size);                                                                                                                                                            
if (rc == -1) { zmq_perror("zmq_getsockopt"); }
```

This is very confusing since the api for zmq_getsockopt is **int**.  Is this a bug?  A windows eccentricity?  Me being dense?

Relevant addendum:

> zmq version: 3.2.3
>
> compiler: cross compiled using mingw-w64, rubenvb-4.8.0 build for both 64bit and 32bit binaries
>
> os: windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zmq_getsockopt man page says,

> Option value type         int on POSIX systems, SOCKET on Windows